# Divider color change React Material Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, material-ui

I'm working with the divider component of the material ui framework and am stuck with the color changing aspect. With most other components from this framework I've been able to change the color by applying the useStyles() method as such:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    textPadding: {
      paddingTop: 10,
      paddingBottom: 10,
      color:'white',
    },
}));
```

But I'm not able to change the color of the dividers using the same approach:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
dividerColor: {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
},
}));
```

I of-course then apply it to the component:

```
<Divider classname={classes.dividerColor}></Divider>
```

I looked up the docs for it but can't figure out what I've done wrong. Could someone give me a helping hand?

Comment: I believe the only issue is that you need `className` instead of `classname` (upper case N). In fact, there should be a warning in the console about it.

Answer (score 17):

use the `classes` API to change the `divider` color:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  divider: {
      // Theme Color, or use css color in quote
      background: theme.palette.divider,
  },
}));


<Divider classes={{root: classes.divider}} />
```

[Divider API](https://material-ui.com/api/divider/), To get your head around [Material UI Theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/)

Answer (score 16):

To change `Divider` line color in MUI v5 you need to adjust your approach depending on whether the element has children or not.

For an empty `Divider`:

```js
<Divider sx={{ bgcolor: "secondary.light" }} />
```

For a `Divider` with content:

```js
<Divider
  sx={{
    "&::before, &::after": {
      borderColor: "secondary.light",
    },
  }}
>
  <Typography>Some Text</Typography>
</Divider>
```

Comparing to the other answers for v5, note that you do not need to nest the SX props under `&.MuiDivider-root` and you can use the theme properties with the SX shorthand strings (e.g., `secondary.light` instead of `(theme) => theme.palette.secondary.light`.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: I like the sx approach.
Sx is a prop utilized to overwrite default styles, but sometimes I don't know if should use CSS or MUI props as a key inside the sx object.
I tried sx={{ color: "primary"}} but it didn't work for some reaso.

Answer (score 12):

You can use
`<Divider style={{ background: 'black' }} variant="middle" />`

Comment: simple ... elegant

Comment: This won't work if the divider has text (i.e. children).

Comment: This was the one that finally worked for me, yes my divider was empty, was trying to use it as a simple bar graph in a table.

Answer (score 4):

You have to override the CSS using classes.

```
<Divider classes={{root: classes.dividerColor}} />
```

See the Material UI docs on CSS overrides: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes

Answer (score 4):

You can directly add color attribute to the divider like so

```js
<Divider color="#FDA228" sx={{ height: 2, width: '92px' }} />
```

the result would be something like this
[image: Divider change color and width]

Comment: This did the trick for me, so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should always use `className` while using `material-ui` styling instead of typical javascript style declaration like `classname`.

You can refer to the official doc also: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api

Answer (score 3):

Using @mui v5 I recognized this was the only way to make it work for myself.

Note:
Because my Divider item has text, the ::before and ::after css
selectors specify which side of the divider to style.

```js
<Divider
    sx={{
        '&.MuiDivider-root': {
            '&::before': {
                borderTop: `thin solid ${theme?.palette.primary['700']}`
            } 
        }
    }}
    style={{
        color: "white",
    }}
    variant="middle"
> Editing as - {username} </Divider>
```

Answer (score 1):

In mui5 if you want to change the Divider color, you must add `width` attribute to `sx`, otherwise it's not work.
With this trick, you can set any color you want:

```
<Divider color='red' sx={{ width: '100%'}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with className :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  divider: {
      background: "white",
  },
}));


<Divider className={classes.divider} />
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the latest MUI(v5), This is how it is done:**

```js
            <Divider
              sx={{ bgcolor: (theme) => theme.palette.divider }}
              style={{
                border: "none",
                height: 2,
                margin: 0,
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do it with createTheme function inside the react component

```
    const Theme = createTheme({
                 components: {
                    MuiDivider: {
                       variants: [
                          {
                             props: { variant: 'dynamic' },
                             style: {
                                ":before": {
                                   borderTop: "thin solid #ffffff"
                                },
                                ":after": {
                                   borderTop: "thin solid #ffffff"
                                },
                             }
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 },
    })
```

> Use it with the variant key in the html component

```
<Divider variant={'dynamic'} flexItem></Divider>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <Divider
          sx={{
            "&.MuiDivider-root": {
              "&::before": {
                border: `thin solid 'your choice of color'`,
              },
              "&::after": {
                border: `thin solid 'your choice of color'`,
              },
            },
          }}
        >
          or
        </Divider>
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.